# How to LIST all occurrences of a string in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some text editors and IDEs have this feature that **LISTS** all the occurrences of a string and displays them as a list.

I have Googled this feature for VSCode, but what I got was mostly 'how to **SELECT** all occurrences'.

What I want is something like this (Notepad++):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's so far not a VS Code feature.

Comment: You can very close to that with a `Search Editor` (context lines of 1).

Comment: use the search bar, second icon on the left

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this is to use the bundled ripgrep that comes with VS Code. You can find it under this path inside the folder your VS Code is installed to:

```
/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg
```

Just open a terminal pane in VS Code with a console of your choice and invoke that ripgrep executable with whatever query is appropriate for the search you want to perform.

You can read more about ripgrep and how to use it on its GitHub page: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep.